# Create a new variable based on other columns values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, panel-data

I have a paneldata dataframe structure, something like this:

```
df <- data.frame("id" = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),          
             "Status_2014" = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
             "Status_2015" = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
             "Status_2016" = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

I want to generate a new dummy variable, that takes the value 1, if the rows contains 1 in any of the three columns or otherwise 0 if not. It should end up like this:

```
df <- data.frame("id" = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),          
             "Status_2014" = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
             "Status_2015" = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
             "Status_2016" = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
             "Final_status" = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))

Can anyone help me achieve this?
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `if_any` on the columns that `starts_with` 'Status', to check for any 1 value in a row and it returns `TRUE` if there is one or else FALSE which is coerced to binary with `as.integer/+`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(Final_status = +(if_any(starts_with('Status'),  ~ . ==1)))
```

-outptu

```
id Status_2014 Status_2015 Status_2016 Final_status
1   1           1           0           0            1
2   1           1           0           0            1
3   1           1           0           0            1
4   1           1           0           0            1
5   2           0           1           0            1
6   2           0           1           0            1
7   2           0           1           0            1
8   2           0           1           0            1
9   3           0           0           0            0
10  3           0           0           0            0
11  3           0           0           0            0
12  3           0           0           0            0
```

---

Or using `rowSums` from `base R`

```
df$Final_status <- +(rowSums(df[-1] > 0) > 0)
```

Comment: When running the suggested code, I only get error: "could not find function "if_any"" - any suggestions?

Comment: The problem was the package version. Code works great. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You write an if condition to define the variable as 1 or 0, and inside this condition the most straight forward ways would be a dplyr pipe.

I don't have the dplyr syntax in my head, to long not used, but dplyr is what you want.

https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf

best greetings